# android:paddingTop overlaps focusof listview item only when the view is created

Tags: android, focus, scrollbar, listviewitem

I've been on this issue since a week and googled a lot, but didn't find a solution. Here goes the problem.

Developing code for a screen with a listview and adapter in android 3.0(HoneyComb). It is a ListView and the rows are set using a custom adapter. The Rectangular focus on the item is also custom. The same layout and the listview is used for many other screens. The layout used for listitems is relative layout and android:padding =17px (padding on all sides).And the list items are more than 8 so that it is being scrolled.

Now, prob is when the view is created for this screen, the focus on the first list item is overlapped by the toppadding of the listview. When the next item is selected i.e., selection(1) and moved back to 0th position, the view is recreated and everything is normal.
If there is no top padding, the focus on the list item is cut at the top.

I have tried something like scrollby(0,-17). If I do that the selection of the last list item is skipped. Its like dragging the listview to the top.

Can somebody provide me a solution or atleast some ideas?

I can give u the code and screenshots tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds weird. I cannot tell what the problem is, but I notice one thing that you should avoid, you should use `dip`(density independent pixel) rather than `px` as unit for defining widths/heights/paddings/margins of your layouts. Otherwise, layouts designed for small screens will not scale when run on devices with big screen, and vice versa.

Comment: How about a screenshot?  I don't really understand what you are seeing from your description.

Comment: i'll update with screenshots.

Comment: SORRY guys, i could nt upload the screenshots until i get 10 reputation it seems. suggest me what should i do abt that...